# JQGrid Sorting - how to trigger onSortCol event

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

I am trying to get the `onSortCol` event get fired when I press a column header. Currently, when I click a column header, I can see a request going to the server but I want the `onSortCol` to be fired before this happens. I have pasted below the code I am using.

Am I missing anything? How do i get `onSortCol` to work?

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false },
{onSortCol:function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder)
 {
    alert(index);
    return 'stop';
 }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You use [onSortCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) in a wrong way. Currently you use [onSortCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) as `prmEdit` (form edit parameters) parameter of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) method. Try include `onSortCol` in the jqGrid definition:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    // other parameters of jqGrid like colModel
    onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
        alert(index);
        return 'stop';
    }
});
```